# How to retrieve rowId of a particular listitem of filtered listview in listActivity displaying SQlite data?

Tags: android, sqlite, listactivity, rowid

Hello Everyone I am new being in ANDROID so I am getting one problem during developing an app using SQLite database. I retrieved some data columns from **SQLite database table**, stored them in an **ArrayList** and **displayed them using ListActivity**. Then I made a nice looking **listview filter** also. Now after filtering I called **onListItemClick** method and after clicking any **position**, I am **getting stuck in retrieving rowId of a particular  listitem of filtered listview in listActivity** and to store it in an integer variable.

Can anyone **HELP** me to know how it is possible.

Any Ideas? I need example code snippets...!!

My Code:

```
package com.aman.samples.dbdemo;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import com.aman.samples.dbdemo.helpers.DatabaseHelper;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Filterable;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class Searching extends ListActivity {

    public static final String KEY_ROWID = "RowId";
    private final String DB_NAME="Database.sqlite"; // data base name 
    private final String TABLE_NAME="Physics";   // table name  
    private SQLiteDatabase myDataBase;
     ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    EditText filterText;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.searching);

        final ArrayList<String> list=new ArrayList<String>();


        myDataBase=this.openOrCreateDatabase(DB_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE, null);
        DatabaseHelper dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(getApplicationContext());
        dbHelper.openDataBase();

        Cursor c=myDataBase.rawQuery(" select * from "+TABLE_NAME,null);
        if(c!=null)  // if c value is not null 
        {
            if(c.moveToFirst())  // movies first column 
            {
                do
                {
                    String nam=c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Law")); // getting specific values regarding column index 
                //  int age=c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("age"));
                    list.add(" "+nam);

                }while(c.moveToNext()); // move to next row

            }
        }


         filterText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.search_box);
        filterText.addTextChangedListener(filterTextWatcher);


        adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, 
                list);
        setListAdapter(adapter);


    }

    private TextWatcher filterTextWatcher = new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
        }

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                int count) {

            adapter.getFilter().filter(s);
        }



    };

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        filterText.removeTextChangedListener(filterTextWatcher);
    }

    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l,View v,int position,long id){
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id );





        if(position==0)
        {

                   Integer rowId = .........// I WANT A SOLUTION OR METHOD TO RETRIEVE ROW ID OF PARTICULAR LISTITEM IN LISTACTIVITY DISPLAYING DATAS FROM SQLITE DATABASE TABLE


            String s=Integer.toString(rowId);

            Intent i=new Intent(this,FinalView.class);
            i.putExtra("key1", s);
            startActivity(i);
        }
        if(position==1)
        {

         Integer rowId = .........// I WANT A SOLUTION OR METHOD TO RETRIEVE ROW ID OF PARTICULAR LISTITEM IN LISTACTIVITY DISPLAYING DATAS FROM SQLITE DATABASE TABLE

            String s=Integer.toString(rowId);

            Intent i=new Intent(this,FinalView.class);
            i.putExtra("key1", s);
            startActivity(i);
        }
        if(position==2)
        {

               Integer rowId = .........// I WANT A SOLUTION OR METHOD TO RETRIEVE ROW ID OF PARTICULAR LISTITEM IN LISTACTIVITY DISPLAYING DATAS FROM SQLITE DATABASE TABLE
            String s=Integer.toString(rowId);
            Intent i=new Intent(this,FinalView.class);
            i.putExtra("key1", s);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [SimpleCursorAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.html) in order to populate list with data from DB. In that case "id" parameter of onListItemClick(l, v, position, id ) will hold id of record.